# Analytic function at a point is analytic in a neighborhood

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion

We have defined today in class:

A function $f:S\to\mathbb{C}$ (where $S\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open) is anayltic at a point $z_0\in \Bbb{C}$ if there exist $R>0$ and a sequence $(a_n)_n\subseteq \Bbb{C}$ s.t. $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ for all $z\in B_R(z_0)$ (the open ball of radius R centered in $z_0$).

My guess is that $f$ would be analytic in this case for every $z_1\in B_R(z_0)$ as well (i.e. has convergent taylor series around $z_1$). For simplicity, let's assume $z_0=0$, $R=1$ and $z_1=\frac{1}{2}$. Probably, now I should be able to view $f$ as $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-\frac{1}{2})^n$ for all $z\in B_\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2})$.

Is this true? Maybe other coefficients? I've tried to do subtitutions with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: If $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ with radius of convergence $R$ then $f$ is analytic at $z_1 \in B(z_0,R)$ with radius of convergence $\ge R-|z_1-z_0|$. This is messy but straightforward to show.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, this was my guess (by the example I wrote with half and one). I couldn't do it though...

Comment: The binomial theorem is your friend :-). And a theorem about 'convolution' of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true. It's a standard theorem about power series that if the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ is $R$, then the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}B_R(z_0)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{C}\\z&\mapsto&\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n\end{array}$$is analytic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you attach some reference for the proof or show it for the specific example I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Kiko Sure. See theorem 4.1 from Serge Lang's *Complex Analysis* (he states it only in the case in which $z_0=0$, but the general case is similar).